# Is there any user guide / manual or a tutorial to learn chrome devtools protocol?

Tags: puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

Is there any user guide / manual or a tutorial to learn chrome devtools protocol?

I have so many questions, I do not get answers online.

For example

1. When we do page navigation, typically we send {"sessionId":"ADE81CEA60DB8988F56A50B1A735809B","method":"Page.navigate","params":{"url":"https://somedomain.com","frameId":"44B75C8EB573492C55A7B44C46C7A759"},"id":16}

   I want to wait till the page access is complete. How do I know when
   the page access is complete.

   Looks puppeteer has the option "await". How puppeteer wait till page
   access / rendering is complete.
2. Puppeteer can run headless chrome both in visible and invisible mode How it is done, can I achieve it using CDP (devtools protocol)

Comment: All the answers are over here: [Puppeteer API](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md)

Comment: If you are trying to understand how the DevTools Protocol works, check out [this guide](https://github.com/aslushnikov/getting-started-with-cdp/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: @SlavaIvanov, My question is how puppeteer achieves objectives like run headless chrome in a visible manner, wait until a page is completely loaded. My understanding is puppeteer, it is using CDP internally, so I wanted to know through CDP how can I do such things. Basically I wanted to have deep understanding of CDP.